# Php class property get and set

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following codes.

```
<?php
class Reg {
    private $pros = array();
    public function __set($key,$val) {
        $this->pros($key)= $val;
    }

    public function __get($key) {
          return $this->pros($key);
    }     
}
$reg= new Reg;
$reg->tst="tst";
echo $reg->tst;
?>
```

But when executing this script I got the error following.
  Fatal error : can't use method return value in write context in line 5

I believe that to add an element to array is possible like the above.

```
 $array = array();    
 $array('key')='value';
```

Please make clear that I was wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Why using round brackets, use square brackets and check

Comment: `$this->pros[$key]`

Answer (score 0):

The is because of you are trying to set a functions return value. `$this->pros($key)` means calling `pros($key)` function. Not setting a value to `$pros` array.

The syntax is wrong. Setting values to [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) be -

```
$array['index'] = 'value';
```

Change

`$this->pros($key)= $val;` -> `$this->pros[$key]= $val;`

and

```
return $this->pros[$key];
```

[Working code](https://eval.in/710454)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->pros[$key] = $value;
```

OR

```
$keys = array($key);
$this->pros = array_fill_keys($keys,$value);
```

The array_fill_keys() function fills an array with values, specifying keys.

Syntax:

```
array_fill_keys(keys,value);
```